# How to make Top Panel and Dock completely transparent? (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: 18.04, themes, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

I want to make the GNOME **top panel** and **dock** completely transparent so that desktop wallpaper is completely visible.

I already created my own theme and added the following css rules. My top panel turned transparent but there is **still** some kind of **gradient** from the bottom. In addition I cant get to work the dock transparency. Instead of transparent it gets black.

```
@import url("/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css");  

#panel {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

#dash {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

#dash .placeholder {
  background-image: none;
}
```

[image]

Comment: @pomsky Thanks! The dock is working but the top Panel still has this bottom gradient using Dynamic Panel Transparency extension.

Comment: @karel Thanks for the link, but using Dynamic Panel Transparency extension results in a partial transparency. Seems like there is some Ubuntu styling involved that applies some kind of gradient.

Comment: Dynamic Panel Transparency should make it completely transparent, but the gradient you've mentioned must be due to something else. You'll have to dig deep into the `ubuntu.css` to find the cause of this effect (or use another GNOME shell theme!).